# Multiple UIActionSheets on the same delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, uiactionsheet

I'm writing a puzzle game. When the user presses the check button, I see if the solution they entered is correct. Depending on the result, I present one of two action sheets for them. For now I just have some NSLog statements to make sure things are getting called, but only one of the sheets seems to work properly.

**Nothing gets called when I click a button in showErrorsActionSheet**. The action sheet disappears off the screen, but the logs never print.

I suspect it has something to do with having two actionsheets declared to the same delegate (self)

```
- (void) checkSolution {

    //code determines the value of the BOOL allCorrect 

    if (allCorrect) { //IF ALL OF THE LETTERS WERE CORRECT
        //display UIAlertView;
        NSLog(@"allCorrect");
        UIActionSheet *levelCompleteActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations! You Have Finished the Level!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Review my work" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Choose next puzzle" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [levelCompleteActionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [levelCompleteActionSheet release];
    }
    else {
        //[self showIncorrectLettersInRed];

        UIActionSheet *showErrorsActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry, thats not right. Show errors in red?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No Thanks, I'll keep trying" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes please, I'm stuck!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [showErrorsActionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [showErrorsActionSheet release];
    }
}
```

the methods that are supposed to be called are:

```
- (void) levelCompleteActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {
        NSLog(@"return to levelSelect");
        //pushViewController:levelSelect
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"continue to examine solution");
    }
}


- (void) showErrorsActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {
        NSLog(@"show errors in red");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"continue to try");
    }
}
```

and Ive declared the UIActionSheet protocol in the interface file as follows:

```
@interface GamePlay : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set a tag for each actionSheet, then use a `switch` statement in the UIActionSheet delegate.

### Assign a tag

```
- (void)checkSolution
{
    if (allCorrect) 
    {
        UIActionSheet *levelCompleteActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations! You Have Finished the Level!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Review my work" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Choose next puzzle" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [levelCompleteActionSheet setTag: 0];

        [levelCompleteActionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [levelCompleteActionSheet release];
    }
    else
    {    
        UIActionSheet *showErrorsActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry, thats not right. Show errors in red?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No Thanks, I'll keep trying" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes please, I'm stuck!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [showErrorsActionSheet setTag: 1];

        [showErrorsActionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [showErrorsActionSheet release];
    }
}
```

### UIActionSheet Delegate

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    switch ( actionSheet.tag )
    {
        case 0: /* levelCompleteActionSheet */
        {
            switch ( buttonIndex )
            {
                case 0: /* 1st button*/
                    break;
                case 1: /* 2nd button */
                    break;
            }
        }
            break;
        case 1: /* showErrorsActionSheet */
            break;
    }
}
```

The same would apply anywhere else in this class as well, including `levelCompleteActionSheet:` and `showErrorsActionSheet:`. The only difference is, you would need to create an iVar for each actionSheet instead of creating them in `checkSolution`.

Answer (score 1):

The methods that will be called by a UIActionSheet on its delegate are the methods listed in the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html

To be called, your method must be one of those methods. I don't see `levelCompleteActionSheet` or `showErrorsActionSheet` listed in that protocol! :) Your method must be named `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`, and not some name you make up out of whole cloth.

Answer (score 0):

Using Tag solve this problem

levelCompleteActionSheet.tag = 100;

showErrorsActionSheet.tag = 101;

```
- (void) levelCompleteActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

  if(actionSheet.tag == 100){

     // levelCompleteActionSheet implement your required function

     }
  else if(actionSheet.tag == 101){

     // showErrorsActionSheet implement your required function

   } 
}
```